# why this is not the array I need?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array `$num_arr` ,so I want  get a new array that It's sum is smaller than 10,so i write the code like this,

```
$num_arr=array(1,3,6,5,4,2,7,9,5,3,6,2,4,7);
$sum=0;
for($i=0;$i<=count($num_arr);$i++){
    $sum+=$num_arr[$i];
    $k++;
    if($sum>=10){
        $need_arr[]=array_slice($num_arr,0,$k);
        array_splice($num_arr,0, $k);   
        $k=0;
        $sum=0;
    }       
}
```

The result $need_arr is not right,that is why and how can get the right array like this: `array(array(1,3,6),array(5,4),array(2,7),array(9),...)`?

Comment: what is the actual result you're currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a "oneliner" just for fun:

```
$num_arr=array(1,3,6,5,4,2,7,9,5,3,6,2,4,7);

$result = array_reduce($num_arr, function($result, $curr) {
    if (!count($result)) {
        $result[] = array();
    }
    $last =& $result[count($result) - 1];

    if (array_sum($last) + $curr > 10) {
        $result[] = array($curr);
    } else {
        $last[] = $curr;
    }

    return $result;
}, array());

var_dump($result);
```

Online demo: http://ideone.com/aFVmkp

Answer (score 0):

Among other things, you are changing the length of the array when you use `array_splice`, but you aren't adjusting `$i` in any way.

In fact, you can remove that `array_splice` line entirely, since you're continuing to iterate over the array.

Also, you're only starting a new array if you're *over* 10. You should change your condition to this:

```
if(!isset($num_arr[$i+1]) || $sum+$num_arr[$i+1] >= 10)
```